# What would cause an HLS stream to just stop streaming?

Tags: video-streaming, jwplayer, http-live-streaming, samsung-smart-tv, m3u8

I am making a samsung smart tv app. I am trying to play a 24 hour stream of a bunch of songs in HLS format, which samsung supports. However, when I play the stream, it plays fine but then when one song ends the stream seems to stop playing on the player (like it just stops receiving content or stops playing the content). I know the stream is still working because it still continues playing on our main website.

Any ideas why this would be?

This is how I format it in samsung:

```
var videoUrl = 'http://mox.tv/hls/moxtv-a.m3u8|COMPONENT=HLS'
```

I am trying with both window.deviceapis.avplay; and sf.services.videoplayer, and both have the same problem.

However, when I load the stream in samsung using jwplayer it works fine in the simulator, but does not seem to work on some tvs.

Comment: Well the stream I am using is in my post: http://mox.tv/hls/moxtv-a.m3u8. The website is in there too. I can't really link to the samsung app, but I could upload the code if that would be helpful.

Comment: Can I see where the player is embedded I mean?

Comment: Do you have access to Apple's mediastreamvalidator tool? It might raise some flags about what's the issue.